# Convert a list of unicode into a string

Tags: python, string, unicode, export-to-excel

This code:

```
 cast_list=final_code.findAll('table',{'class':'cast_list'}) 
 for i in cast_list:
    j=i.findAll('span',{'itemprop':'name'})   
    print "Cast List: "
    for x in j:
        print x.text+","
```

produces an output like this:

```
Cast List: 
Robert Mitchum,
Jane Greer,
Kirk Douglas,
Rhonda Fleming,
Richard Webb,
Steve Brodie,
Virginia Huston,
Paul Valentine,
Dickie Moore,
Ken Niles
```

If I try to write the above in an Excel workbook every entry gets added in a different cell. However, I want all the above to fit in one cell i.e. basically this gets converted to a string. I want the desired output which takes just one cell of my workbook.

> Cast List: Robert Mitchum,Jane Greer,Kirk Douglas,Rhonda Fleming,Richard Webb,Steve Brodie,Virginia Huston,Paul Valentine,Dickie Moore,Ken Niles

I tried the standard method of converting a list into a string using the code below, but that also isn't working. It still tries to writes one entry per one cell.

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
str1 = ''.join(list1)
```

Comment: Was able to figure it out :)

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer? This would help other people with the same problem. You also might get some comments on your code and some hints if there are better ways to do this ;)